# how to Retrieve firebase database start from bottom to up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a set of items in firebase realtime,
when i Retrieve data the old data appears at the first.
Already i tried

```
    Firebase.database().ref().child('chains').orderByKey().startAt();
```

- but the data didn't appear

I want upload new item and it appear at the first how do i do this?

this my code:

[image]

this my database

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How do you determine which items is newer? Is there any child node containing timestamp? If yes then you should use `orderByChild()`:

```js
firebase.database().ref('chains').orderByChild('addedAt')
```

However this will sort by ascending order and hence oldest items will be retrieved first. If you are looking for latest 50 items then you can use `limitToLast` method and then reverse the order using Javascript:

```js
firebase.database().ref('chains').orderByChild('addedAt').limitToLast(50)
```

If you are ordering them using the item keys then you can use `orderByKey` but to get items in descending order i.e. newest first, you'll have to use same logic with limitToLast.

Comment: Hi, i tired this methods but didn't work im getting same result

Comment: @AliAlsaggaf please share a screenshot of your database so I can check it once.

Comment: i uploaded screenshot you can check