# How to get users document id in Firestore using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**how to get only the last document id in Firestore?**

i tried

```
                    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
                //set document from firestore
                    var date=new Date();  
                    var day=date.getDate();  
                    var month=date.getMonth()+1;  
                    var year=date.getFullYear(); 
                    if (user){
                        db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('orders').doc().set({
                            things:cart,
                            orderState: "Order pending",
                            date:day+'/'+month+'/'+year,    
                        })
                        //get document from firestore
             db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('orders').doc().get()
             .then(snapshot => console.log(snapshot.id))
     })
```

the result i'm getting wrong id thats not in the orders document!!

[image]

**This is my documents :**

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what order you are referring to?

Comment: i want get the new order id but the problem i'm facing  when i call the order id its coming wrong id , you can check the last order id in firestore is (
sRUMtGcX50BjmvOVAaoF) , but when i called in console tool its coming (BfoJBL0sSsYQesbbSXP0) not the same ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('orders').doc()` twice which creates 2 different [DocumentReferences](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) and hence they are different. If you are trying to get the document that you just added try this:

```js
if (user) {
  db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('orders').doc().set({
    things:cart,
    orderState: "Order pending",
    date:day+'/'+month+'/'+year,    
  }).then((ref) => {
    console.log(ref.id)
    // ref.get() get document
  })  
}
```

```js
const ref = db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('orders').doc()
console.log("Doc ID:", ref.id)
ref.set({...data}).then((snapshot) => {
  console.log(`Document ${snapshot.id} added`)
  // This ID will be same as ref.id
})
```

Comment: Can you give me the answer for this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521452/how-to-retrieve-firebase-database-start-from-bottom-to-up